# Exception: Method not found: execute_kw

Tags: java, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8

I am calling create method of OpenERP through XMLRPC by:

```
Object[] valuesAllOL = new Object[]{ record };
Object[] all = new Object[]{TINY_DB, uid, PASSWORD, tableName, CREATE_OP, valuesAllOL};

Integer id = (Integer) xmlrpcClient.execute(COMMON_METHOD, all);
```

Where `record` is a `hashmap`.

And:

```
COMMON_METHOD = "execute_kw";
CREATE_OP = "create";
```

I've got the following error:

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 75, in xmlrpc_return
    result = openerp.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 114, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/common.py", line 23, in dispatch
    raise Exception("Method not found: %s" % method)
Exception: Method not found: execute_kw
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check the URL of the xmlrpc endpoint. Are you using `http://servername:port/xmlrpc/2/object`
2. check the server logs, there could be some important information there
3. check that you can send an http query from the server running the java code to the server running odoo with curl or wget on `http://servername:port/xmlrpc/2/object` to make sure that there are no proxy/firewall issue